# Getting all unique field-array combinations from the entire collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have the following collection

```
{
  _id:1,
  item:"cat"
  keywords:['A','B']
},

{
  _id:2,
  item:"cat"
  keywords:['B','C']
},

{
  _id:3,
  item:"dog"
  keywords:['C','D']
},
```

I would like to get the following results:

```
[{"cat", "A"}, {"cat", "B"}, {"cat", "C"}, {"dog", "C"}, {"dog", "D"}]
```

Basically creating the combinations between item and keywords and removing duplicates.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Expected output is not a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) on array and then you can use `$group` (by constant value) to get all elements into one array and [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) will handle uniqueness of specified pairs:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$keywords"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            unique: { $addToSet: { item: "$item", keyword: "$keywords" } }
        }
    }
])
```

You can then use onother `$unwind` on `unique` field to get a list of documents instead of single document as a result.